# ios 6 - canperformaction not getting called on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on adding custom shared menu. I followed this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290828/how-to-show-a-custom-uimenuitem-for-a-uitableviewcell) to implement this also seen some other posts.

It is working as it should be. But I am getting problem to get called `canPerformAction` when coming on this UITableView Controller by UITabBar item action which navigate me back to this view.

I tried to sovle this problem by using one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879429/uimenucontroller-not-working-as-expected-canperformaction-not-getting-fired) on stackoverflow. But still `canPerformAction` not getting called in this case

Any help in this case is appritiated. Thanks

EDIT: My code looks like:

On viewDidLoad, i am doing following

```
UIMenuItem *sendByEmailMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send e-mail" action:@selector(sendEmail:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: @[sendEmailMenuItem]];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];
```

These are delegate methods i have used

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {

}

- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return (action == @selector(sendEmail:));
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void) sendEmail: (id) sender {
       //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Doubt this will fix the issue, but do check your third delegate method; should be a (void)tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath instead of BOOL

Comment: @azsromej: Thanks, I followed the post in question. I will check it from docs and change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue. Posting it if some one needs it.

I have added a call to become fist respoder on `shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath` action

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

This fixed my issue. Thanks